# Double filter for a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I've read a number of articles and forum posts but haven't quite figured out how to improve on the below. I have a list of dictionaries that need to be filtered in two ways.

```
jsonData = [{'a':'1a', 'b':'1b', 'c':'1c'},{'a':'2a','b':'2b', 'c':'2c'}, {'a':'3a','b':'3b', 'c':'3c'}]
```

I want to remove any dictionary within the list where the key c corresponds to 3c. The first line below achieves that. Then I want to only retain the b and c keys and corresponding values. This is what the rest does. It all works but I'm wondering if the second part can also be expressed in a list comprehension and if there are any other ways to simplify this.

```
jsonData = [i for i in jsonData if i['c'] != '3c']
for i in range(len(jsonData)): 
    jsonData[i] = {key:value for key,value in jsonData[i].items() if key in ['b','c']}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the set-like nature of keyviews to limit the search of `d` to only the keys you'd actually use instead of iterating all of them.

```
jsonData = [{k: d[k] for k in (d.keys() & {'b', 'c'})} for d in jsonData if d['c'] != '3c']
```

If this is on Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.x, then `d.keys()` should be `d.viewkeys()`.

Comment: Performance-wise, you'll want to test whether it's best to use the set-literal I used or a set created once outside the comprehension, and whether to put it on the left or right of the creation of the keysview; this could easily differ due to small implementation details, so if performance is a serious concern, you'll want to verify.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your solution worked perfectly. Will have a closer look at performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would do the trick:

```
[{key:value for key,value in jdata.items() if key in ['b', 'c']} 
 for jdata in jsonData if jdata['c'] != '3c']
```

it returns

```
[{'c': '1c', 'b': '1b'}, {'c': '2c', 'b': '2b'}]
```

given the provided list.